# FabricGateway.exe goes into a boot loop after a server reboot

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a on prem Service Fabric 3 Node cluster running 8.2.1571.9590. This has been running for months without any problems.

The cluster node were rebooted overnight, as part of operating system patching, and the cluster will now not establish connections.

If I run `connect-servicefabriccluster -verbose`, I get the timeout error
`System.Fabric.FabricTransientException: Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints.`

Looking at the processes running I can see all the expected processes start and are stable with the exception of `FabricGateway.exe` which goes into a boot loop cycle.

I have confirmed that

- I can do a TCP-IP Ping between the nodes in the cluster
- I can do a PowerShell remote session between the nodes in the cluster
- No cluster certs have expired.

Any suggestions as to how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

### Actual Problem

On checking the Windows event logs *Admin Tools > Event Viewer > Application & Service Logs > Microsoft Service Fabric > Admin* I could see errors related to the startup of the `FabricGateway` process. The errors and warnings come in repeated sets with the following basic order

> CreateSecurityDescriptor: failed to convert mydomain\admin-old to SID: NotFound
> failed to set security settings to { provider=Negotiate protection=EncryptAndSign remoteSpn='' remote='mydomain\admin-old, mydomain\admin-new, mydomain\sftestuser, ServiceFabricAdministrators, ServiceFabricAllowedUsers' isClientRoleInEffect=true adminClientIdentities='mydomain\admin-old, mydomain\admin-new, ServiceFabricAdministrators' claimBasedClientAuthEnabled=false }: NotFound
>
> Failed to initialize external channel error : NotFound
>
> EntreeService proxy open failed : NotFound
>
> FabricGateway failed with error code = S_OK
>
> client-sfweb1:19000/[::1]:19000: error = 2147943625, failureCount=9082. This is conclusive that there is no listener. Connection failure is expected if listener was never started, or listener / its process was stopped before / during connecting. Filter by (type~Transport.St && ~"(?i)sfweb1:19000") on the other node to get listener lifecycle, or (type~Transport.GlobalTransportData) for all listeners

Using Windows Task Manager (or similar tool) you would see the `Fabricgateway.exe` process was starting and terminating every few seconds.

The net effect of this was the Service Fabric cluster communication could not be established.

### Solution

The problem was the domain account `mydomain\admin-old` (an old historic account, not use for a long period) had been deleted in the Active Directory, so no SID for the account could be found. This failure was causing then loop, even though the admin accounts were valid.

The fix was to remove this deleted ID from the cluster nodes current active `setting.xml` file. The process I used was

1. RDP onto a cluster node VM
2. Stop the service fabric service
3. Find the current service fabric cluster configuration e.g. the newest folder on the form `D:\SvcFab\VM0\Fabric\Fabric.Config.4.123456`
4. Edit the `settings.xml` and remove the deleted account `mydomain\admin-old` from the `AdminClientIdentities` block, so I ended up with

```
<Section Name="Security">
  <Parameter Name="AdminClientIdentities" Value="mydomain\admin-new" />
  ...
```

5. Once the file is saved, restart the service fabric service, it should start as normal. Remember,it will take a minute or two  startup
6. Repeat the process on the other nodes in the cluster.

Once completed the cluster starts and operates as expected